# Is there a preprocessor constant for memory size

Tags: compile, sketch-size, avr-gcc, gcc

I would like my compiles to exclude some code depending upon the flash/program space available. To be used in the demo code of a library I support. Whereas my current solution is to use a #ifdef of processor type. But I would like to be more general and not have to specify all the various chips. Rather it would be nice if there was a pre-processor constant that stated the available size.

Where I am not fluent enough in gcc and or avr-gcc I might expect to find some constants similar those that define the beginning and end of the heap.

On case example. Is that both the UNO and Leo have 32K of Flash. But the Leo's core library uses 4K for USB support, resulting in only 28K available. My Library's demo is near max'ed out on the UNO and I would like to automatically trim out based on available program space.

Comment: I've seen programs that do this, but I can't find any

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find the `io__.h` file for your microcontroller, on Linux it is located in `/usr/lib/avr/include/avr`, on Windows it will be in a somewhat similar location.

Scroll down to the part that says `/* Constants */`. There are couple interesting macros defined there, `FLASHEND` being the one you should be interested in. You can use it for example as follows:

```
#if FLASHEND > 0x8000
/* Include some extra code when sufficient flash is available. */

#endif
```